# Is there any tool can visualize nested type definitions(e.g. c++ struct or protobuf)?

Tags: types, graphviz, graph-visualization, mermaid

is there any tool can visualize (complicated) nested type definitions? maybe a vs code extension or standalone app?

e.g. I got a c++ struct defination (or `protobuf`, ros `msg` or other similars)

```cpp
struct A
{
  float x = 0.0;
  float y = 0.0;
}


struct B
{
  float a = 0.0;
  float b = 0.0;
}

struct C
{
  A a;
  B b;
}
struct D
{
  A a;
  B a;
  C c;
}
```

then by this tool, I can get a graph (or generate graphviz/mermaid code) like

```
graph LR

D --> A("A a");
D --> B("B b");
D --> C("C c");

A --> x("float x");
A --> y("float y");

B --> a("float a");
B --> b("float b");

C --> A;
C --> B;
```